# R PCA plot - R adds column to imported data

Tags: r, pca

I have a dataset that I am trying to analyze with PCA. The first column of my dataset is an ID and then the rest of the data. However, R adds on a first column to the dataset so that instead of the ID I want assigned to each row, it uses "1" , "2", "3", etc. as the row identifier. There is an R dataset I practiced with called mtcars - in this dataset it used the car names as each row identifier. How do I remove/prevent R from adding on a column that makes each row identifier an integer?

[image]

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Pictures of data are not very helpful because we can't interact with them.

Comment: This has nothing to do with PCA,  just how you imported the data.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done as follows

```
Data = read.csv("filename.csv",  row.names=1) # 1st column should contain the row names
```

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you!

Comment: If it answers your question, then please accept the answer as correct. It will give you some reputation as well as to myself.